# Index initializer warning during bootstrap

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I'm trying to simultaneously add 4 nodes to my current 2-node DC. I have Vnodes turned off as per Datastax suggestion. Right after the major index build in each node, the following warning is printed several times in the logs:

> WARN [SolrSecondaryIndex ks.cf index initializer.] 2014-06-20
>   09:39:59,904 CassandraUtil.java (line 108) Error Operation timed out -
>   received only 3 responses. on attempt 1 out of 4 with CL QUORUM...

I understand what it means. But why is Cassandra expecting the nodes to fulfill the CL when these nodes are still bootstrapping? More importantly, how does the warning affect the bootstrap? I noticed that the nodes are not doing any index build or streaming anymore; but they also remained in "Active - Joining" state. Is there any chance that they will finish? What should I do?

I'm using DSE 4.0.3. All existing and new nodes in the DC are Search nodes. I pre-computed the tokens using the python program for MurMur3Partitioner.

EDIT:

Although *nodetool compactionstats* does not show any on-going index build in the nodes, for some reason, I still see a lot of these lines in the logs:

```
 INFO [IndexPool backpressure thread-0] 2014-06-20 12:30:31,346 IndexPool.java (line 472) Throttling at 26 index requests per second with target total queue size at 40
 INFO [IndexPool backpressure thread-0] 2014-06-20 12:30:34,169 IndexPool.java (line 428) Back pressure is active with total index queue size 18586 and average processing time 2770
```

EDIT:

Interestingly, I found the following lines in each node after digging through the log files:

```
INFO [main] 2014-06-20 09:39:48,588 StorageService.java (line 1036) Bootstrap completed! for the tokens [node token]
INFO [SolrSecondaryIndex ks.cf index initializer.] 2014-06-20 11:32:07,833 AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java (line 411) Reindexing 1417116631 commit log updates for core ks.cf
```

Based from these lines, I feel a lot safer that the bootstrap actually completed and that the nodes are simply re-indexing their data. I don't know, though, why the re-indexing process is not being shown in nodetool compactionstats.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the bootstrap completed, and the DSE Search system is running normally.

> why the re-indexing process is not being shown in nodetool compactionstat

DSE Search is not generally exposed via Cassandra command line tools.  The log output should show the indexing as having completed, were you able to verify that?

Comment: Yes. After 3 days, 3 out of the 4 nodes that I'm trying to bootstrap have completed the re-indexing of the commitlog. They are now part of the ring. About the progress not showing up in nodetool, as far as I remember: 1. Solr indexing shows up in nodetool compactionstats when you manually trigger reindexing via Solr _RELOAD_ with _reindex=true_. 2. Solr indexing during bootstrap/repair/decommission also shows up in compactionstats. That's why I'm wondering: what's different with this commitlog re-indexing that it does not show up in nodetool?